# My prog do not fetching Marathi database values in exiting PDF template

Tags: php

Can anybody help me why my code is not fetching Marahti database values in PDF.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php
    GLOBAL $html;
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root') or die('Error');
    mysql_select_db('DemoMarathi');
    $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8")or die('error'.mysql_error());

      $cmd = "select * from Demo_hindi";
      $result = mysql_query($cmd);

      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
      {

         $html .= '<td>'.$row['DemoMarathi'].'</td><td>' . $row['DemoValues']. '</td>'; 
         $pdf->Text(105, 73,"hi".$myrow['DemoMarathi']);
         $pdf->Text(105, 73,"hi".$myrow['DemoValues']);

         $pdf->Write(75,"".$myrow['DemoMarathi']);
         $pdf->Write(90,"".$myrow['DemoValues']);

      }
       include('MPDF FULL_PACKAGE/mpdf60/mpdf.php');
       $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
       $mpdf->WriteHTML($html.$myrow['DemoMarathi']);
       $mpdf->WriteHTML($html.$myrow['DemoValues']);
       $mpdf->Output();
       exit;
?>
```

[PDF OUTPUT FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj4Xm.png)

Comment: @Legionar was that edit really necessary and all that you could do?

Comment: Yes, the formatting was wrong at the beggining.